# How to get all security groups through AWS CLI of an EC2 to show in a table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jmespath

I am trying to show all instances along with attached security groups, block device name and their deleteontermination status. I need to show this data in table format but I am continuously getting the below error.

Kindly help me to understand what I am missing here.

```
PR-MacBook-Pro:~ pr$ aws ec2 describe-instances --output table --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,SecurityGroups[].GroupName,Placement.AvailabilityZone,BlockDeviceMappings[].DeviceName, BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.DeleteOnTermination]'

Row should have 1 elements, instead it has 2
PR-MacBook-Pro:~ pr$
```

Comment: What is `some data`?

Comment: It is due to the hierarchical nature of the information you are retrieving, which is not compatible with a 2-dimensional table. Can you explain more why you require it in a table rather than as Text or JSON? What is the end goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually I need to show this data to management. I feel tabular representation would be good for them to understand as they are non-technical and it would be difficult to understand text or Jain format.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this while searching in google.

After I did a bit of research I found that you have to use `` | join(`, `, @) ``

So the command will be

`` aws ec2 describe-instances --output table --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,SecurityGroups[].GroupName | join(`, `, @),Placement.AvailabilityZone,BlockDeviceMappings[].DeviceName | join(`, `, @), BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.DeleteOnTermination | join(`, `, to_array(to_string(@)))]' ``

Answer (score 1):

modify your command as below to make it work

```
aws ec2 describe-instances  --output table  --region "us-east-1"  --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,SecurityGroups[].GroupName |[0],Placement.AvailabilityZone,BlockDeviceMappings[].DeviceName |[0], BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.DeleteOnTermination|[0] ]'
```

the response was in the format of

```
[
    [
        "i-xxxxxxxx", 
        [
            "xxxxxx"
        ], 
        "us-east-1a", 
        [
            "/dev/xvda"
        ], 
        [
            true
        ]
    ]
]
```

so you need parse the array element using `| [0]`

Comment: I had already tried your solution @Madhan but it gives me only first security groups. I have one instance attached to multiple security groups and your command gives only first security group of all instances.
 `| i-0bdfd84101cc29f5d | NewSG | us-west-2c | /dev/sda1 | True |

  | i-075e4a319eefdad0 | NewSG | us-west-2c | /dev/sda1 | True |

  | i-07682f7reb1bd946 | NddewSG | us-west-2c | /dev/sda1 | True |`