# Create awscli table output with EC2 Instance Name and Private IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, jmespath

If I don't try and put into a table, this is the output

```
[
    [
        "naaws_01"
    ], 
    "[\"172.24.7.96\",\"172.24.3.248\"]"
]
```

Using this command

```
aws ec2 describe-instances  \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[].[ Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value, NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddress[] |  join(`,`, to_array(to_string(@))) ]'  \
    --profile famc-prod \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --output table
```

The result is a table with name and IP address in a single column. I'm not able to split on [name],[list of IP address]

Comment: Thank you. I did try that but I got a single column with name, Private IpAddress. I believe I resolved it; see my explanation below. I followed, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56671906/7802257.

Comment: Thank you.for cleaning up, jarmod

Answer (score 1):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances  \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[].[ Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value |  join(`, `, @), NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddress[] |  join(`, `, to_array(to_string(@))) ]' \
   --profile famc-prod \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --output table
```

A couple of things I discovered...

First, I was trying to string together the query and then pass to the join to_array.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[].[ Tags[?Key==Name].Value, NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddress[] | join
```

Following the example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56671906/7802257

I noticed that it was query | join the next item | join the next item | join to array

The way I was doing it originally the results are,

```
[
    [
        "naaws_01"
    ], 
    [
        "172.24.7.96", 
        "172.24.3.248"
    ]
],
```

Notice the pattern [], [] - I couldn't parse that

Using the correct answer the results are (ignore the results; focus on pattern)

```
[
    [
        "i-07c722b2a227ff5e6", 
        [
            "All internal"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Now, with a "comma" it can be parsed into a table.

Hope my explanation helps.